# Data not indexed in ajax solr

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene

I am using solr to index my data from my local MYSQL DB.

- data-config.xml contains my entity information as follows:

  ```
  <entity name="distinctWeeksVolumeEntity" dataSource="mysqlLocal" rootEntity="false" query="select week as distinctWeeksVolume, count(`distinct` tweetid) as weeklyTweetVolume from twitter.tweetbisect tb group by week" transformer="TemplateTransformer">
                  <field column="distinctWeeksVolume" template="distinctWeeksVolumeEntity" />
                  <field column="weeklyTweetVolume" template="distinctWeeksVolumeEntity" />   </entity>
  ```
- schema.xml has the information

  ```
  <field name="distinctWeeksVolume" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
  <field name="weeklyTweetVolume" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  ```

When i go to the dataimport of solr admin and execute import I get the following message

```
    Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
    Requests: 1, Fetched: 3, Skipped: 0
```

I am using full-import with the commit option true

Why am I not able to index the data ?? 
Kindly help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, You don't need `TemplateTransformer` in this use case.

You could use data-config to look like

```
<entity name="distinctWeeksVolumeEntity" dataSource="mysqlLocal" rootEntity="false" query="select week as distinctWeeksVolume, count(`distinct` tweetid) as weeklyTweetVolume from twitter.tweetbisect tb group by week">
</entity>
```

Since your `select` query gets the fields named exactly as the Solr Schema, you don't even need to specify `field` under `entity.

However, if you must use `TemplateTransformer`, try something like this:

```
<entity name="distinctWeeksVolumeEntity" dataSource="mysqlLocal" rootEntity="false" query="select week as distinctWeeksVolume, count(`distinct` tweetid) as weeklyTweetVolume from twitter.tweetbisect tb group by week" transformer="TemplateTransformer">
                <field column="distinctWeeksVolume" template="${distinctWeeksVolumeEntity.distinctWeeksVolume}" />
                <field column="weeklyTweetVolume" template="${distinctWeeksVolumeEntity.weeklyTweetVolume}" />   </entity>
```

Which, seems quite inefficient, IMHO.

Read more about `TemplateTransformer` [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#TemplateTransformer)